# Firebase installation error with "Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.19.0 and node@12.1.0"

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am trying to install firebase on my MacBook, and is getting the following error.

```
$ npm install -g firebase

> grpc@1.19.0 install /Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.19.0/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.19.0 and node@12.1.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /anaconda3/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/bin/node" "/Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v12.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/bin/node /Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/bin/node" "/Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.1.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/bin/node /Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.19.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.19.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/satoshi/.npm/_logs/2019-04-30T20_15_40_148Z-debug.log
```

I have npm (6.9.0) and node (12.1.0). It looks like a type of version mismatch, but I am not able to find out how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This work for me:

```
install nvm from  https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
switch to node version : v10.15.3
```

Comment: Hey there! Please make yourself familiar with formatting code samples on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I appreciate it, but it did not solve the problem. I still see the same error messages.

Comment: Switching to v10.15.3 has solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Ran into this issue in the scope of grpc@1.22.2 in `firebase`, and found that node 14 LTS support isn't available until grpc@1.24.3, similarly, this now means locking any node versions to 12 instead of auto updating to 14 (the next LTS.) Leaving this here for anyone discovering it after recently updating `firebase`

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that grpc 1.19.0 is not compatible with Node 12. Version 1.20.2 of grpc is compatible with Node 12, so if Firebase updates their dependency that will also fix the problem.